# ¿como verificar que el usuario que intento registrar ya existe?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5

Acá esta el proceso guardar:

```
$nuevoobjeto= new Objeto();

$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$nombres = $_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$telefono1 = $_POST['telefono1'];
$telefono2 = $_POST['telefono2'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$municipio = $_POST['municipio'];
$parroquia = $_POST['parroquia'];
$vulnerabilidad = $_POST['vulnerabilidad'];
$grupo= $_POST['grupo'];
$fecha_ingreso = $_POST['fecha_ingreso'];
$fecha_donacion = $_POST['fecha_donacion'];
$formacion_psico = $_POST['formacion_psico'];
$fecha_psico = $_POST['fecha_psico'];
$formacion_plan = $_POST['formacion_plan'];
$fecha_plan = $_POST['fecha_plan'];
$observacion = $_POST['observacion'];
$indicador_psico = $_POST['indicador_psico'];
$suspendida = $_POST['suspendida'];




    $foto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']));


    // $consulta=$nuevoobjeto->lista($cedula);
    // if ($cedula) {
    //  echo "<script> alert('usuario ya existe') + window.open('?accion=registrar','_self');</script>";
    // }else{



$nuevo=$nuevoobjeto->insertar($cedula, $nombres, $apellidos, $telefono, $telefono1, $telefono2, $direccion, $municipio, $parroquia, $vulnerabilidad, $grupo, $fecha_ingreso, $fecha_donacion, $formacion_psico, $fecha_psico, $formacion_plan, $fecha_plan, $observacion, $indicador_psico, $suspendida, $foto);

    // }        

 ?>
```

Y acá esta la sentencia que termina de guardar los datos a mi tabla:

```
public function insertar($cedula, $nombres, $apellidos, $telefono, $telefono1, $telefono2, $direccion, $municipio, $parroquia, $vulnerabilidad, $grupo, $fecha_ingreso, $fecha_donacion, $formacion_psico, $fecha_psico, $formacion_plan, $fecha_plan, $observacion, $indicador_psico, $suspendida, $foto)
    {
        $sql=$this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `perfiles` (cedula, nombres, apellidos, telefono, telefono1, telefono2, direccion, municipio, parroquia, vulnerabilidad, grupo, fecha_ingreso, fecha_donacion, formacion_psico, fecha_psico, formacion_plan, fecha_plan, observacion, indicador_psico, suspendida, foto) VALUES ('$cedula', '$nombres', '$apellidos', '$telefono', '$telefono1', '$telefono2', '$direccion', '$municipio', '$parroquia', '$vulnerabilidad', '$grupo', '$fecha_ingreso', '$fecha_donacion', '$formacion_psico', '$fecha_psico', '$formacion_plan', '$fecha_plan', '$observacion', '$indicador_psico', '$suspendida', '$foto')"); 
        $sql->execute();
        if($sql){
        echo "<script> alert('Se ha Guardado con EXITO') + window.open('?accion=registrar','_self');</script>";

            }
```

Verán ya el sistema hace casi todo lo que quiero pero necesito que el sistema me muestre que el usuario que estoy intentando registrar ya existe en la base de datos.

Comment: Lo que quieres es que valide si ya exisiste el usuario ??

Comment: Lo mas facil es vereficar si su cedula esta, haciendo una consulta a la tabla, ya q la cedula es unica para una persona

Comment: si exacto es justo lo que quiero pero no logro hacerlo supongo yo que antes de que haga el proceso guardar debo colocar una condición para que primero haga consulta?

Comment: Así es, primero un SELECT para ver si existe y de caso contrario, hacer INSERT, sino, UPDATE o nada, según tu necesidad.

Answer (score 4):

Podría probar de la siguiente manera:

```
$a = $db->query("INSERT INTO nombres (nombre, apellido, cedula) 
    (SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$nombre', '$apellido', '$cedula') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT cedula FROM nombres WHERE cedula = '$cedula') 
    LIMIT 1)")
```

Esta inserta los datos siempre que no existan ya en la tabla, claro esta que si realizar un var_dump() este estara siempre en true;

La otra opción es poner como UNIQUE el campo clave de la validación y realizar un try catch

```
try{
    $a = $db->query("INSERT INTO nombres (nombre, apellido, cedula) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula')");
    if(!$a){
        throw new Exception("Error ".$db->error,1);
    }
    var_dump($a);
}catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Con este tienes más control, ya que tu decides que retorna la función para validar si se registro o no, en este caso, nos retornara un error parecido a este: **string(49) "Error Duplicate entry '16401771' for key 'cedula'"** indicando que el dato cédula ya se encuentra registrado en la tabla y por ende no se realizo el registro.

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

1. Que la columna en tu BD sea UNIQUE, lo puedes lograr del modo siguiente

   ALTER TABLE perfiles ADD UNIQUE (campo_nombre);

2.- Una vez que intentas hacer el alta, lo puedes verificar de este modo, desde PHP

```
if ($resultado->fetchColumn() > 0) {
    echo "El usuario ya existe"
}else{
   echo "el usuario no existe";
}
```

> Siempre va a ser mejor que tu primer verificación o validación la
>   hagas desde el gestor de bases de datos, con el atributo UNIQUE para
>   que evites valores duplicados

Answer (score 1):

Una opción sería hacer una consulta con los datos únicos del usuario antes de insertar los datos o, una validación a nivel base de datos agregando un valor UNIQUE:

```
ALTER TABLE perfiles 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX campo_unico_UNIQUE (campo_unico ASC)
```